# Dockerized Django can't connect to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-machine

Using this tutorial https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application, I'm dockering my Django application in a VirtualBox using `docker-machine`. Everything has gone splendidly until I go to my browser and my application says that it's having issues with MySQL.

Then i found this documentation for dockerizing an instance of mysql https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker which I followed, creating the image in the same development VirtualBox that I created. The error I was originally getting was

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

My Django DATABASES looked like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

I then changed the host to `127.0.0.1` and even tried specifying the port as `3306` and I got a new error which was

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

I also went in to MySQL workbench and changed the connection of my Local instance to be `127.0.0.1:3306` and that hasn't helped.

The commands that I'm running are

`eval "$(docker-image env development)"` ---> supposedly does THESE things:

```
         export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
         export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://123.456.78.910:1112"
         export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/development"
         export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="development"
```

Then, now that i'm in my virtualbox, I run:

`docker run -it -p 8000:8000 <docker image name>` ---> forwards exposed port 8000 to port 8000 on my local machine

`docker run -it -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-sever` ---> forwards exposed port 3306 to port 3306 on my local machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to connect with `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` which from the perspective of the django container will refer to itself and not to the mysql container.

In general, for containers to communicate, the best "docker way" is to make the containers share a common docker network.

```
docker network create mynet
docker run -it --network mynet -p 8000:8000 <docker image name>
docker run -it --network mynet -p 3306:3306 --name mysql mysql/mysql-sever
```

Now the application container can connect to mysql using `mysql` as a hostname and `3306` as the port.

Comment: My understanding is that Docker automatically links the running containers to the default ‘bridge’ network. In fact, with both containers running, if I run ‘Docker inspect network bridge’ it shows both containers running on the bridge network with each of their individual IP addresses... I tried creating a custom network and running them the same way you did with no success again...

Comment: Yes containers are attached by default to the default bridge network. They can communicate however using only IPs and not DNS names. `Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge network` https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network

Comment: So are you saying that I need to change my HOST in my DATABASES config to “mysql” in order for it to access the MySQL database, after connecting on a custom network?

Comment: @Naji Yes. And make sure you give the my-sql container the name `mysql` as specified in the answer.